# 'setTimeout' was used before it was defined

Tags: javascript

This is the only error I'm getting for my code now.

'setTimeout' was used before it was defined.

It occurs due to this line:

```
setTimeout("a()");
```

What should I do about it in order to pass validation? This is my full code:

```
/*global document, window */
function checkTime(i) {
    'use strict';
    if (i < 10) {
        i = "0" + i;
    }
    return i;
}
function a() {
    'use strict';
    var oct = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"],
        octtime,
        oct1,
        oct2,
        oct3,
        oct4,
        oct5,
        oct6,
        octvalue,
        point = ".",
        now = new Date(),
        hours = now.getHours(),
        minutes = now.getMinutes(),
        seconds = now.getSeconds(),
        h = checkTime(hours),
        m = checkTime(minutes),
        s = checkTime(seconds),
        totsecs = [hours * 3600 + minutes * 60 + seconds + (now.getTime() % 1000) / 1000];
    octtime = Math.floor(totsecs / (86400 / 262144));
    oct1 = Math.floor(octtime / 32768);
    octtime -= 32768 * oct1;
    oct2 = Math.floor(octtime / 4096);
    octtime -= 4096 * oct2;
    oct3 = Math.floor(octtime / 512);
    octtime -= 512 * oct3;
    oct4 = Math.floor(octtime / 64);
    octtime -= 64 * oct4;
    oct5 = Math.floor(octtime / 8);
    octtime -= 8 * oct5;
    oct6 = octtime;
    octvalue = point + oct[oct1] + oct[oct2] + oct[oct3] + oct[oct4] + oct[oct5] + oct[oct6];
    document.getElementById('a').innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
    document.getElementById('b').innerHTML = octvalue;
    setTimeout("a()");
}
window.onload = a;
```

Comment: I used this http://codebeautify.org/jsvalidate .

Comment: Nobody bothered to explain *why* your code was failing: Using the parenthesis in "a()" is the same as *calling the function immediately*, then passing the return value of calling `a()` to setTimeout. You just needed `"a"` or better yet `setTimeout(a)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you could try in this way, you have already this correct line

```
/*global document, window */
```

just call `setTimeout` with the prefix of `window`

```
window.setTimeout(a);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're developing for a browser environment - declare it: [set the environment](http://jshint.com/docs/options/#browser) instead:

```
/*jslint browser: true, devel: true */
```

This will enable everything in browsers - so you can drop the window/document globals too.

While you're at it, pass it the function rather than a string

```
setTimeout(a); // and not "a()"
```

Comment: Nope. not gonna work because the function is not defined yet and registered in the global context. There is still that last bracket to parse and the setTimeout races it.

Comment: @MichaelDibbets no, that's not how browsers work. Of _course_ you can call `a` inside - that's just recursion.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I tried already. It results in:

Implied eval is evil. Pass a function instead of a string.
setTimeout("a()", 50);

Comment: That's my second comment - use `a` instead of `"a()"`